# How to add text in SWFDotNet

Tags: c#, flash

I am new to Flash programming. I don't have too much knowledge about how tags in Flash/SWF works. This may be a reason of my failuer. How ever would you please check this code and tell me where I am making mistake?

```
Swf swf = new Swf();
DefineTextTag dtt = new DefineTextTag();
TextRecord tr = new TextRecord();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello"));
SwfDotNet.IO.Utils.BufferedBinaryReader reader = new SwfDotNet.IO.Utils.BufferedBinaryReader(ms);
bool flag = true;
tr.ReadData(reader, ref flag, TagCodeEnum.DefineText2);
tr.TextColor = RGBColor.FromWinColor(Color.Black);
tr.XOffset = 10;
tr.YOffset = 10;
dtt.TextRecords.Add(tr);
dtt.Add("Hello World");
dtt.UpdateData(1);
swf.Tags.Add(dtt);
swf.Tags.Add(new ShowFrameTag());
SwfWriter writer = new SwfWriter("Quiz 1.swf");
writer.Write(swf);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: No. I just replaced technology. Used HTML with JS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have to use `placeObject2`, or some such tag, to get the `defineText` information into the display list, before you can use `showFrame`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please clarify your explanation? Perhaps, by adding a code snippet or the modified code from the question to demonstrate your answer?